# 'popping' off an element in an arraylist. what am I missing?

Tags: java, arraylist

Alright the input is a string of numbers and operators such as, + 2 3 * 4. I want to split the string up into an ArrayList object, with each character in the string getting it's own index. Here's what I have;

```
String current;
String s = "+ 2 3 * 4";
List <String> splitter = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+")));
current = splitter.remove(0);

if (current == "+"){
   //do stuff }
else if (current = "-") {
   //do stuff } 
....
```

The if statements aren't being evaluated as true for some reason, am I missing something subtle or am I completely wrong here?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you cannot compare a `String` using the `==` operator, you need to use `.equals()`

Comment: yes, and (current = "-") as an condition shouldnt even compile, because it is assigment, not comparation (use == to compare and .equals() to compare objects)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `if`, you are using `==` to compare strings; use [`String#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead.

In the `else`, you are using the assignment operator `=` to compare strings; use `String#equals` instead.

The `==` operator compares the two string references to see if the refer to the same object, which is not what you want.